# Couldn't install git-flow on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, git

I am trying to install `git-flow` on Ubuntu 10.04 but I am getting the following error:

```
eading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package git-flow
```

I have exected these instructions

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-flow
```

But didn't work. I got the above error. I am able to install using the following commands

```
wget -P ~/Downloads http://launchpadlibrarian.net/84618376/git-flow_0.4.1-2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/git-flow_0.4.1-2_all.deb
```

But I don't understand why the first set of commands doesn't work. What could be the possible issue.

Comment: "E: Couldn't find package git-flow" means that the package is not on the server as you described it.

Answer (score 0):

```
git_flow_pivotal (0.0.9)
git_reflow (0.3.2)
git_workflow (0.0.5)
gitflow (0.0.1)
```

Querying the gem server, I get that listing.  Nothing looks right.

Checking the official repository is often a great way to get information.  So I went there and found this installation page for Ubuntu/Debian

https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/Linux

Which says to do this:

```
$ apt-get install git-flow
```

Or you could do the [manual installation](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/Manual-installation).